Large Number data type in ms access , I can't update
This is my test code.
Private Sub test()
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim size As LongLong

        rs.Open "Select * From LocalFiles ", _
                CurrentProject.AccessConnection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
                
         rs.AddNew
         size = 12345678912345#
         rs("FileSize") = size
         rs.Update  <-- show  error Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors
         rs.Close

End Sub


It show error in line rs.Update
"Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors"
In my database, field FileSize is Large Number data type.
I already enabled it. and it have new database (Large Number)
I define type LongLong in VBA to store this data.
But when update this field , it show error above.
I google and it seem to may because OLE DB drive does not support this data type.
I don't sure about it.
How can I update data. please recommend me.
Thank
I try to not assign value to rs("FileSize") and it work, so it 's relevant with this line only.
I try to google to solve problem but don't find any.

Any reason you're using CurrentProject.AccessConnection? Quoting the docs: You should use the AccessConnection property if you intend to create ADO recordsets that will be bound to Access forms

I had similar problem and forced to use Currency instead of LongLong field.

@Erik I used CurrentProject.AccessConnection long time ago, and it has no problem. I don't like to open connection with long connection string
and thank you for your comment , it make me found solution

@h2oyesss The normal way to do that is CurrentProject.Connection. You don't need to manually specify the string.

Finally, I found 2 solutions.

use Provider OLEDB 12 or OLEDB 16

Note: I found that CurrentProject.AccessConnection use OLEDB 10 Provider
Private Sub test1()

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim size As LongLong
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=d:\data\Make Money\Rapidgator\Rapidgator.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    rs.Open "Select * From LocalFiles ", _
            cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
     rs.AddNew
     
     size = 12345678912345#
    rs("FileSize") = size
    rs.Update
    rs.Close
    cn.Close

End Sub

Use ADODB

Private Sub test2()
Dim size As LongLong
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
     Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From LocalFiles ", dbOpenDynaset)
     size = 12345678912345#
     rst.AddNew
     rst("Size1") = size
     rst.Update
     rst.Close

End Sub

@h2oyesss The normal way to do that is CurrentProject.Connection. You don't need to manually specify the string. –

This make me wonder that If I use currentproject.connection , It may work.
and really. currentproject.connection use OLE DB 12


Private Sub test1()
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim size As LongLong

        rs.Open "Select * From LocalFiles ", _
                CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
         rs.AddNew
         size = 12345678912345#
        rs("FileSize") = size
        rs.Update
        rs.Close

End Sub



